# WITH statement not working in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL Query which I run in PgAdmin:

```
WITH TABLE1 AS
( SELECT int1, int2, int3 FROM atbl
)
SELECT int1, <complex computation involving a large number of values of int2 and int3 from TABLE1>
FROM TABLE1
```

The result of running it is an error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: WITH TABLE1 AS
```

Why does this happen? The with statement should be available for PostgreSQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

It is understood that this version is lower than 8.4. Is there an alternative to using WITH to achive the same results?

Comment: I can't say for PostgreSQL, but I know SQL Server gets confused if the previous statement wasn't terminated with a semicolon. Is your query part of a large batch?

Comment: As you linked to the 8.4 docs, you do use PostgreSQL 8.4, right? :)

Comment: It's actually version 8.1.17. Didn't think this through, really. It seems the WITH statement was introduced after this version...

Comment: That's correct, WITH was introduced in 8.4. But why do you use 8.1 anyway? It's end of life, unsupported.

Comment: So is there anything that I can use instead of the WITH statement? In the second select for every row from the first query I need to do some computation involving ALL the data from that table. I would like to avoid having to do the first query all over again to achieve this...

Comment: @Frank Heikens: because the application I work on uses it, and currently I don't know of any plans to change it :(

Comment: Just use a simple SQL. But could you show us the real problem? WITH can't work because of the old version you use. (be aware of the security risks!)

Comment: @mstaniloiu: How about using temporary tables?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/CTEReadme) and [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html) helpful. and make sure your using a version >= 8.4 as that's when this was introduced. Not having a ; shouldn't be an issue.

Your syntax looks correct though... this definitely works.

```
WITH table1 AS (
SELECT * FROM atbl
)
select * from table1
```

So I'd check the version you are running. as that give the error your are experiencing.

Comment: Not really... I still need to figure out how to do this without using the WITH statement

Comment: @mstaniloiu, temporary table is the way to go then.

Comment: @mstaniloiu, I did answer the question which is why it wasn't working. and yes the temp table would be an alternative, but I'd upgrade if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with the following:

```
SELECT int1, 
       (complex computation involving a large number of values of int2 and int3 from TABLE1)
FROM ( 
   SELECT int1, int2, int3 
   FROM atbl
) table1
```